# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'QLPreviewControllerDataSource'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, quicklook, arcgis-runtime

I'm facing a very strange issue, my code is working well utill I upgrade my argis 100.4 to 100.5 version.

As soon as I updated the version I am getting issue at build time. `QuickLook framework's` **`QLPreviewControllerDataSource`** protocol is giving issue at build time.

In the swift class I **`import QuickLook`** and extends the data source method after class name. But at the build time in the "`PROJECT_NAME-swift.h`" file it is showing error that `QLPreviewControllerDataSource protocol` not found even this protocol is in the same class(`QLPreviewController`)

[image: Kindly see the screenshot for more information]

I guess, Issue is not related to arcgis but it occurs after updating version

Comment: How did you installed it? If you downgrade it to the previous working version? Could it be related to the known issue in XCOde 10.2 and Swift5 where headers changed?

Comment: I upgraded it from 100.4 version to 100.5, but I also tried removing whole arcgis library and then directly installing the 100.5 version but it didn't work, but if I did same in another new sample project its working

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'll do some investigating, but it seems an interim workaround would be to also provide an `@protocol QLPreviewControllerDataSource` line in your `PROJECT_NAME-swift.h`.

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution for this yet, what I observed is when I revert from version 100.5 to 100.4 the code start working without any issue.

Comment: Does the above suggestion about declaring the `QLPreviewControllerDataSource` protocol similarly to how `QLPreviewItem` is declared on line 291 not help?

Comment: We can only reproduce this under specific conditions (importing the `PROJECT_NAME-swift.h` file into a `.mm` file rather than a `.m` file, where the `@import QuickLook` is wrapped in a `#if __has_feature(modules)`, and C++ doesn't yet support modules), however we see it with both 100.4 *and* 100.5. Did anything else also change, such as Xcode version? My above suggestion allows our test project to compile, but still generates a warning. Also, are you using Cocoapods or downloading the SDK directly?

Comment: Sorry for replying late, I tried using your above suggestion by writing "@protocol QLPreviewControllerDataSource", but still its giving error and doesn't compile. Yes I checked it is wraping QuickLook module in __has_feature(modules) condition. I'm using cocoapods to update it. Is there any appropriate solution ? I'm curious to know why updating the arcgis version giving error in a very different module compilation ?